# For loop vb.net increase

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have got a small question.If I made a for loop like this that increase myvar value by 30 if remainder of a division is 0.

```
  Dim myvar As Integer = 49
        For i As Integer = 0 To myvar
            Console.WriteLine("Pasada " & i)
            If Math.IEEERemainder(i, 3) = 0 Then
                myvar += 30
            End If
        Next
```

How can I make to change the for repetitions to the new value of myvar??

Comment: That would jump directly to 30 since 0 is divisible by 30. Is that really what you want? In that case, `For i = 0 To myvar Step 30` solves your problem.

Comment: No.What I want is if myvar is increased to 120,the for loop continues to 120 and not to 49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use Do Loop

```
Dim myvar As Integer = 49
Dim i As Integer
    Do While i <= myvar
        Console.WriteLine("Pasada " & i)
        If Math.IEEERemainder(i, 3) = 0 Then
            myvar += 30
        End If
        i +=1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the boundaries of a `For` loop (for good reasons), so you’ll have to replace `For` with a manual loop:

```
Dim myvar = 49
Dim i = 0

While i <= myvar
    Console.WriteLine("Pasada " & i)

    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        myvar += 30
    End If

    i += 1
End While
```

Comment: It also worked,but the solution provided by xavigonza is much clear than this.Also thank you

Comment: @Cako “much cleaner” – are you kidding? It’s virtually the same, except for using `Do While` instead of `While`, and having broken formatting. How is that cleaner? (in fact, I’ll go ahead and claim that my solution is cleaner since I’m using type inference in declarations and thus avoid repeating unnecessary type names, which is generally agreed to be a good thing).

Comment: oh sorry.Viewing better are same.Thanks also.I will consider of using it